# I am getting null pointer exception in android when calling findviewbyID

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/longitude_val"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="14dp"
    android:text="Lattitude"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.194"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.373" />
```

Hi I am very confused, why i am getting error on findviewbyId
I am doing as following
longitude_val=(TextView) longitude_val.findViewById(R.id.longitude_val);

Comment: the id in the xml is  `Lattitude` , and you are trying to get it with the id  `longitude_val`

Comment: Is this in a fragment? if not it's just longitude_val = findViewById(R.id.Lattitude);

Comment: I am sorry i just mistyped. my id's are same in xml file and main activity

Answer (score 0):

You have defined this id for the TextView:

```
android:id="@+id/Lattitude"
```

this means you should stick to that id when you use findViewById too. You code should then be:

```
TextView yourTextView = findViewById(R.id.Lattitude);
```

Comment: I am sorry i just mistyped. my id's are same in xml file and main activity

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an NPE because you are trying to find the id of an element that doesn't exist, `longitude_val`. Your id that you defined in your xml layout file is `Lattitude'. Your code to find this view should be this:

```
lattitudeTextView = (TextView) longitude_val.findViewById(R.id.Lattitude);
```

Comment: I am sorry i just mistyped. my id's are same in xml file and main activity

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all you shouldn't name object in your java code in snake_case format.Use camelCase.

**Second**, your TextView had id of Lattitude and you're trying to assign an object to id of longitude_val.

Try this:

```
longitude_val=(TextView) longitude_val.findViewById(R.id.Lattitude);
```

Comment: I am sorry i just mistyped. my id's are same in xml file and main activity